# Vagrant Connection timeout error

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to follow instructions in a book which involve bringing up a vagrant instance based on a `Vagrantfile` that I downloaded from `git clone https://github.com/jorhett/learning-puppet4`. For convenience, here are the contents of the `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.5.2"

# Copy files into place
$setupscript = <<END
  # Hardlock domain name
  echo 'supercede domain-name "example.com";' > /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

  # Install etc/hosts for convenience
  cp /vagrant/etc-puppet/hosts /etc/hosts

  # Install puppet.conf in user directory to quiet deprecation warnings
  #mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet
  #cp /vagrant/etc-puppet/puppet.conf /home/vagrant/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet
  #chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.puppetlabs

  # Install example hiera settings in global directory
  mkdir -p /etc/puppetlabs/puppet
  cp -r /vagrant/etc-puppet/* /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/
  mkdir -p /etc/puppetlabs/code
  chown -R vagrant:vagrant /etc/puppetlabs

  # Provide the URL to the Puppet Labs yum repo on login
  echo "
You should start by enabling the Puppet Labs Puppet Collection 1 release repo
   sudo yum install http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-el-7.noarch.rpm

Then install Puppet 4 and its companion packages
   sudo yum install -y puppet-agent

" > /etc/motd
  # Enable MotD
  sed -i -e 's/^PrintMotd no/PrintMotd yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  systemctl reload sshd
END

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-nocm"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "off"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "off"]
  end

  # Default client
  config.vm.define "client", primary: true do |client|
    client.vm.hostname = "client.example.com"
    client.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.250.10"
    client.vm.provision "shell", inline: $setupscript
  end

  # A puppetmaster
  config.vm.define "puppetmaster", autostart: false do |puppetmaster|
    puppetmaster.vm.hostname = "puppetmaster.example.com"
    puppetmaster.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.250.5"
    puppetmaster.vm.provision "shell", inline: $setupscript
  end

  # Puppet Server
  config.vm.define "puppetserver", autostart: false do |puppetserver|
    puppetserver.vm.hostname = "puppet-server.example.com"
    puppetserver.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.250.6"
    puppetserver.vm.provision "shell", inline: $setupscript
    puppetserver.vm.provider :virtualbox do |ps|
      ps.memory = 1024
    end
  end
end
```

When running `vagrant up client` I get the following output that ends with an error:

```
Bringing machine 'client' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> client: Importing base box 'puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-nocm'...
==> client: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> client: Checking if box 'puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-nocm' is up to date...
==> client: Setting the name of the VM: learning-puppet4_client_1439117612834_66
905
==> client: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> client: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    client: Adapter 1: nat
    client: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> client: Forwarding ports...
    client: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> client: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> client: Booting VM...
==> client: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    client: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    client: SSH username: vagrant
    client: SSH auth method: private key
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    client: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

How to troubleshoot and fix this error?

Comment: Taking a guess here. Your hardware can't support ,64 bit virtual guests. Open virtual box and run the virtual machine though that and a more useful error will show up

Answer (score 0):

This is happening at a really low level -- the Vagrant instance isn't booted far enough for provisioning to happen, so nothing you quoted from the Vagrantfile is relevant.

Look for an issue with the Vagrant setup on your machine, and check your machine's logfiles. In particular, check for out of memory conditions.

You can try reducing the Vagrantfile to something really simple, without any of the provisioning stuff and work with that until the virtual machine boots up.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.5.2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-nocm"
  # Default client
  config.vm.define "client", primary: true do |client|
    client.vm.hostname = "client.example.com"
    client.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.250.10"
  end
end
```